# Dynamically change page contents on click

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue using a Pug template used along with express framwork app. I currently have a list of JSON docs retrieved inside of my `index.js` file. I send this as `messageList` when I render my template. The UI I'm going for is similar to a regular email GUI, where subjects appear on the LHS, and when clicked it opens the message/email on the center of the page.

[the GUI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDB1d.png)

Each JSON has a *subject* and *message* field as String. I am currently iterating/looping through each `entry` in `messageList` and displaying each *subject* as inner text to a `button`. My thought process is that I want to use `onclick()` to send the entries from `message` to display inside my `readMessage` div.

Here is code

**Index.js**

```
app.get("/dashboard", (req, res) => {
  Message.find( {}, function(err, data){ //data is my json doc list
     if(err)  
      return console.error(err);
     res.render("dashboard.pug", {messageList: data})
   })
});
```

**dashboard.pug**

```
    .messages   
         each entry in messageList
          button.clickableMessage(onclick = '') /*where I want to send the msg data to be displayed below in p.messageText*/
            .unreadIndicator
            p.innerText #{entry.subject}
        span
        .readMessage
          p.messageText
            | Feedback:
            | Hi Bruce, I am in your class and I wanted to let you know that I really like
            | such and such about it. Thanks for such and such. I only wish you would do more
            | X, Y, and Z in class. Have a good one
```

So far I have tried to use `script` in the pug file to do DOM manipulation, as well as rendering the page multiple times but the issue comes down to the `onclick()` displaying the value in `p.message` text nested in `.readMessage.`

This was my script attempt. I realize that appendChild is most likely not what Im looking for.

```
  script. 
   msg = function putMsg(message){
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("readMessage");
    div.innerHTML = `<p class = "messageText"> ${message} </p>`;
    document.querySelector(".readMessage").appendChild(div);
   }
   .messages
     each entry in messageList
      button.clickableMessage(onclick = "msg( #{entry.message})")
       .unreadIndicator
       p.innerText #{entry.subject}
    //span 
    .readMessage
      p.messageText 
       | this is where i want my #{entry.message} to display when a subject button clicked
```

I am new to pug and web dev in general and am really struggling! any input is appreciated.

Comment: show us what you've tried in your script. Why is it a problem that onclick must displaly the value in `p.message`?

Comment: As an aside, as a new developer, I would recommend against investing in a technology like pug, whose user base has been shrinking for some time already

Comment: Its mostly that I am unsure of what other method to use. I can add the script as well

Comment: I don't know that I have enough room in the comment, I'll submit an answer but it may not have the full story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript code looks mostly good, although it does look like it will append another `.readMessage` as a *child* of the current `.readMessage`. I.e.

```
    .readMessage
      p.messageText 
       | this is where i want my #{entry.message} to display when a subject button clicked
      .readMessage //<-- dynamically inserted into DOM by JS code
        p.messageText
          | message
```

You can confirm this by opening the Developer Tools in your browser and looking through the DOM. It may be worth learning how to use the debugger in the Developer Tools.

What you probably want to do is replace that node instead:

```
function putMsg(message) {
  const newReadMessage = document.createElement("div");
  newReadMessage.classList.add("readMessage");
  newReadMessage.innerHTML = `<p class = "messageText"> ${message} </p>`;
  const oldReadMessage = document.querySelector(".readMessage");
  const parent = oldReadMessage.parentNode;
  parent.replaceChild(newReadMessage, oldReadMessage);
}
```

This is more or less straight out of the [MDN documentation for `replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild#example).

### Comments and suggestions

#### Selectors

You'll probably want to assign an ID to the node you're replacing and use that as your selector (multiple elements can use the same class, but ID should be unique in the document).

#### Logical DOM organisation

It probably also makes sense to move your `.readMessage` element to the same level as your `.messages` element (this might just be a spacing error in the code pasted above), and both of these should not be children of `script` element.

#### File organisation

If it doesn't complicate your route logic, you'll probably want to move your Javascript into a separate file, if you can. Doing this will enable you to better leverage the tools available for Javascript, and make it easier to test your code

#### Frameworks and technology

Pug is a technology that is on the decline. It is absolutely fine for generating static HTML, though as you can see it does not offer any help for dynamic content. The method used by your JS code to display the selected message is known as *DOM manipulation*, and DOM manipulation inside event listeners is largely considered hard to maintain in larger projects, as event listener that manipulate the same HTML elements are often located in very different parts of the code. This makes it hard to know what code depends on other code when making changes. For example, if you needed to add another `div` between `.readMessage` and `p.messageText`, you would have to search all of your Javascript to try to locate any code that replaces that element and make your changes there. You may want to look into a front-end framework like React (although admittedly there are isn't a defacto starter kit/code template to create a project with Express on the backend and React on the frontend - this may make it hard to integrate React into your project).